# Strip last empty row of a string?

Tags: php, regex

I know about `^` and `$`, but I want to remove the last empty row of a string, not each.

```
$s = 'Foo

Bar

Baz
';
```

should return as

```
$s = 'Foo

Bar

Baz;
```

How could it be done in PHP with regex?

You can try it here: http://codepad.viper-7.com/p3muA9

Comment: Why not simply use rtrim() rather than more complex regexp?

Comment: actually he can use `rtrim()` to strip whitespace from the end of the string.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php

$s = 'Foo

Bar

Baz
';

$s_replaced = preg_replace('//', '', $s);

$s_replaced = rtrim($s_replaced);
$out = '<textarea cols=30 rows=10>'.$s_replaced.'</textarea>';

echo $out;

?>
```

Use `rtrim()`.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$s_replaced = preg_replace("/".PHP_EOL."$/", '', $s);
```

Comment: You must have the magical view to know the row-ending TS writes about. And for which operating system have you written the code specifically?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

**Find with:**

```
(?s)\s+$
```

**Replace with:**

```
none
```

**Explanation:**

```
<!--
(?s)\s+$

Options: case insensitive; ^ and $ match at line breaks

Match the remainder of the regex with the options: dot matches newline (s) «(?s)»
Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, and line breaks) «\s+»
   Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
Assert position at the end of a line (at the end of the string or before a line break character) «$»
-->
```